# Error in solving ODE45

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve Ordinary Differential Equations with ODE45, but I get the following error. I have tried my best to debug the program, but the error still persists. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
function dp = suspension_seat_z_model_1(t,p,cushion_interface_vel_z,cushion_interface_dis_z)

load('C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Program - Post Processing\model_mfiles\resample_filter_add_1s.mat','cushion_interface_acc_z','cushion_interface_dis_z','cushion_interface_vel_z','ts1')


V = cushion_interface_vel_z;
D = cushion_interface_dis_z;

% define constant parameters

mh1=13.9; % lower part of the dummy (kg) 
mh2=47.9; % upper part of the dummy (kg)
ch=1100; % damping_co-efficient_dummy (Ns/m)
kh=42000; % stiffness_co-efficient_dummy (N/m)
kcz=35000; % spring_stiffness_cushion (N/m)
ccz=1500; % damping_co-efficient_cushion (Ns/m)

dp=zeros(4,1);

dp(1)=p(2);
dp(3)=p(4);
dp(4)=((kh/mh2)*(p(1)-p(3)))+((ch/mh2)*(p(2)-p(4)));
dp(2)=((kcz/mh1)*(D-p(1)))-((kh/mh1)*(p(1)-p(3)))+((ccz/mh1)*(V-p(2)))-((ch/mh1)*(p(2)-p(4)));

end
```

ERROR MESSAGE

[T P] = ode45(@(t,p)suspension_seat_z_model_1(t,p,cushion_interface_vel_z,cushion_interface_dis_z),[0 305],[0 0 0 0]')
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in suspension_seat_z_model_1 (line 26)
dp(2)=((kcz/mh1)*(D-p(1)))-((kh/mh1)*(p(1)-p(3)))+((ccz/mh1)*(V-p(2)))-((ch/mh1)*(p(2)-p(4)));

Error in @(t,p)suspension_seat_z_model_1(t,p,cushion_interface_vel_z,cushion_interface_dis_z)

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Comment: What this means is that `((kcz/mh1)*(D-p(1)))-((kh/mh1)*(p(1)-p(3)))+((ccz/mh1)*(V-p(2)))-((ch/mh1)*(p(2)-p(4)))` is not a scalar. Check the size of each part of the expression, and make sure they give a scalar, particularly `V` and `D`.

Comment: @david    y=zeros(1,4); 
for i = 1:length(ts1)-1
    [T,P] = ode45(@(t,p)trial(t,p,V(i),D(i)), ts1(i):0.01:ts1(i+1), [y(i,1) y(i,2) y(i,3) y(i,4)]);  
    y(i+1,:) = P(end,:);
end  I tried running with this code but still the problem exists. Any further suggestion

Comment: That is odd. Right before the `dp(2)=...` line, put in `size` commands for all the variables in the equation for `dp(2)`, `size(kcz)`, `size(mh1)`, etc. If any of them are not 1x1 scalars that may be your problem. If they are all scalars, then I don't know what could be happening!

Comment: @ David   I used the following code and it works now for i=1:length(ts1)-1; V=V(i); D=D(i); V and D were vextors obtained from a accleration vector. With the help of for loop I just take an instance of the value  and execute the ODE equations